# How to execute a statement on a NSManagedObjectContext's thread

Tags: ios, multithreading, swift, core-data

I have the following CoreData Context Hierarchy. PSC -> PrivateQueueContext (for saving) -> MainContext (for UI) -> several PrivateQueueContexts to perform e.g. JSONMapping.

I am running in the following problem. I use Alamofire to call a web service for some data. In the completion block I perform the JSON Mapping in a context.performBlockAndWait. I initialise my class in the performAndWait of the context. But somehow the mapping is performed on the main thread, even it is in the performBlockAndWait. Does someone can tell my why this happens and has a solution to dispatch this to another thread than the MainThread?

BR
Dominik

Comment: Why do you think that it is executed in the main thread?

Comment: I see it in instruments, and when the mapping is performed, the UI does not react to user inputs.

Comment: And I added an assert(!NSThread.isMainThread()) which results in an assertain